# Failed opening required '/var/www/html/sel/demo/../bootstrap.php' for Nearsoft/php-selenium-client

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I have **PHP v 7.1.8 / PHPUnit v 6.4.4** successfully installed on my machine.
I dowloaded Nearsoft/php-selenium-client (https://github.com/Nearsoft/php-selenium-client).

After I started selenium standalone server, I tried to run demo Nearsoft Demo test **phpunit Demo1.php**, but it shows:
"Failed opening required '/var/www/html/sel/demo/../bootstrap.php'"

Not sure why, because it works just fine on my other machine that uses **PHPUnit v 4+ amd PHP 5.6**

Comment: Does the file exist?  Does the user that run your php (probably via Apache) have rights to access that directory and file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can run those demos with PHPUnit v6.4.4, since v6.0 PHPUnit has changed its Class names. Try running it with PHPUnit v5.7.

Take a look at the [Release Notes for PHPUnit v6.0](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-6.0.0#backwards-compatibility-issues).
A quick look at [demo1.php at line 10](https://github.com/Nearsoft/php-selenium-client/blob/master/demo/Demo1.php#L10) exposes the "old" naming schema for PHPUnit.